# Problema la retornar variables privadas

Tags: java

No logro retornar el resultado en un método abstracto ya que me dice que las variables son privadas a pesar de haber configurado los métodos `get` y `set`

Clase estándar:

```
public class Triangulo extends Poligono implements FigueGeometrica {

    public Triangulo(double altura, double base) {
        super(altura, base);
        setBase(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Base de triangulo")));
        setAltura(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Altura de triangulo")));
        getBase();
        getAltura();

    }

    @Override
    public double calcularArea() {
        return (base*altura)/2;
    //aqui es donde ocurre el problema. 
    }

    @Override
    public double calcularPerimetro() {
        return 0;


    }
```

Clase abstracta:

```
public abstract class Poligono implements FigueGeometrica  {

    private double altura;
    private double base;




    public void setAltura(double altura) {
        this.altura = altura;
    }

    public void setBase(double base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public double getAltura() {
        return altura;
    }

    public double getBase() {
        return base;
    } 

    public Poligono(double altura, double base) {


    }



}
```

Interface:

```
public interface FigueGeometrica {


    double calcularArea();
    double calcularPerimetro();

}
```

Comment: En lugar de tener tus variables privadas ponlas como protected asi las clases hijas podran acceder a ellas directamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa porque los atributos privados no se heredan y solo son accesibles por la clase que los contiene. Si deseas accederlos debe ser con sus getter y setter

```
@Override
public double calcularArea() {
    return (getBase()*getAltura())/2;
//aqui es donde ocurre el problema. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de implementarlo sería llamando a la función dónde quieres realizar los cálculos y pasando-le los valores mediante llamadas al getter de las variables en cuestión.

```
public class Triangulo extends Poligono implements FigueGeometrica {

    public Triangulo(double altura, double base) {
        super(altura, base);
        setBase(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Base de triangulo")));
        setAltura(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Altura de triangulo")));
        calcularArea(getBase(), getAltura());
    }

    @Override
    public double calcularArea(Double base, Double altura) {
        return (base*altura)/2;
    //aqui es donde ocurre el problema. 
    }

    @Override
    public double calcularPerimetro() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```